# Retrieve the asplabel data and include the same in an url

Tags: asp.net, label

Pls help me to sort this issue. I need in display dynamic data in a Chart (Google Charts)

I have these datas in an asplabels, I need those datas to be inserted in the Charts url dynamically.

Assume the label ids are as follows:

I need to use those label values to the following url
http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=c,s,C3D9FF&chxr=0,0,**lblDayLimit,lblMonthLimit** 1&chxt=x&chbh=32,3,0.

Kindly help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Do something like the following:

Declare protected string variables:

```
 protected string DayLimit = string.empty;
 protected string MonthLimit = string.empty;
```

Set them when you set the values of the labels:

```
 DayLimit = lblDayLimit.Text;
 MonthLimit  = lblMonthLimit.Text;
```

Then use them on the page, when constructing the URL like:

```
 http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chf=c,s,C3D9FF&chxr=0,0,<%=DayLimit%>,<%=MonthLimit%>&chxt=x&chbh=32,3,0
```